# Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'model' while creating user in Django Abstract User class

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I created the Abstract User model in my Django project. I'm able to create a superuser but facing error in create_user cmd. Following is my piece of code. Thank you in advance.

My Views.py FIle:

```
def index(request):
    user=AccountManager.create_user("alb@alb.com","albas","12345")
    user.username="alba"
    user.save()
    return HttpResponse(f"User created {user.username} - {user.email}")
```

My Models.py file:

```
class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):

def create_user(self,email,username,password=None):
    
    if not email:
        raise ValueError("User Must have an e mail address.")
    if not username:
        raise ValueError("User Must have a Username.")
    
    user=self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        username=username,
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user


def create_superuser(self,email,username,password):
    user=self.create_user(
        email,
        password=password,
        username=username,
    )
    user.is_admin=True
    user.is_staff=True
    user.is_superuser=True 
    user.save(using=self.db)
    return user
```

**Error Am Receiving:**

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner    
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Python\projects\Practise\Django User class\trialcode\trialcode\views.py", line 12, in 
index
user=AccountManager.create_user("alb@alb.com","albas","12345")
File "C:\Users\Python\projects\Practise\Django User class\trialcode\Userclass\models.py", line 17, in 
create_user
user=self.model(
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'model'
[22/Jul/2020 13:32:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 71321
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call `AccountManager.create_user` directly.

Assuming your model is something like,

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    objects = AccountManager()
```

then you would call the `create_user` method as follows:

```
MyUser.objects.create_user(...)
```